# What does the 'address' in configtx.yaml refer to?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In the Hyperledger fabric configuration of configtx.yaml, what does the below address refer to? is it the name_of_container:container_port OR is it the address_of_the_machine_where_container_is_running:container_port

```
Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050
```

Similarly, what does the below refer to? Is it the container_name OR the hostName of the machine?

```
    AnchorPeers:
        - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
```

Answer (score 1):

They define the `name_of_container:container_port` . Now, these containers can be running on the same machine or on a different machine depending upon how to spin up your network. [This](https://medium.com/@wahabjawed/hyperledger-fabric-on-multiple-hosts-a33b08ef24f) is a good tutorial to get you started on different implementations of Fabric network.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
Addresses:
    - orderer.example.com:7050
```

section defines list of routable endpoints for ordering service nodes (OSN). The value should be machine host name or ip address which would be resolvable by peers networks as they will use it to connect to the ordering service to pull blocks. In most of examples it would be equal to docker container name, while doesn't have to be like that, you just need to keep in mind that peer will use that value to get connected to OSN.

Next,

```
AnchorPeers:
    - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
```

Section which list peers which would be used by other organization to exchange peers membership information to enable cross organization replication of ledger. You can read more in [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/glossary.html#anchor-peer).